# Как изменить версию dependency в child pom не меняя parent pom (maven)

Tags: java, maven

Нужно изменить версии некоторых dependencies в child pom при этом не внося изменений в parent pom от которого child pom наследуется. Как это сделать?
В parent'e dependencies прописаны БЕЗ тэга dependencyManagement.

Comment: а вы не пробовали просто добавить зависимость с нужной версией в дочерний pom.xml?

Comment: сорри за поздний ответ. Пробовала. Но не помогло. Пока кроме использования dependencyManagement ничего не помогло. Видимо все-таки нельзя по другому